# javascript does not always fire in correct order an sometimes breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

Im a little bit stumped on  this for a number of reasons, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. When you narrow the view port to less than 945px the subnav elements should toggle but sometimes they do not. I am also getting some unexpected results.

I have a codepen here

https://codepen.io/robbiemcmullen/pen/BqdRpN

my code is as follows:-

```
 //toggle for subnavs
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //only toggle if window size is less than 945px
            $(window).resize(function(){

                var submenu = $('.nav-wrapper');

                if (window.innerWidth < 945) {
                    $(document).on('click','nav ul li',function() {

                        $(submenu).toggle();

                    });
                }
            });

            var listItem = $('.navigation-toggles__list-item');

             //hide mega menu when settings activated
             $(listItem).mouseleave(function(){
                      $(userMenu).hide();
             });

             var userIcon = $('.navigation-user-icon'),
             userMenu = $('.dashboard-user-menu');

            //toggle dashboard menu
             $(userIcon).click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
                    $(userMenu).toggle();
            });


        });
```

can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine. Every time I resize, it collapses. Can't replicate issue.

Comment: if (window.innerWidth < 945) {} doesn't work. That's the problem, removed it and works ok but ideally want to fire this on window resize, it does work on some instances, but has weird behaviour sometimes ???

Comment: The problem is, the "weird" behavior can't be replicated on a consistent basis. Also, you're not being very specific about the exact problem, you just say "weird behavior" and "unexpected results". We can't help if we don't _specifically_ what we're looking for, or _specifically_ how to replicate the issue.